# Whose responsibility is creating Akka actor's children when it fails?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Akka's documentation correct quote says:

> the precise sequence of events during a restart is the following:
> Suspend the actor (which means that it will not process normal
> messages until resumed), and recursively suspend all children.

A misleading quote says:

> Resuming an actor resumes all its subordinates, restarting an actor
> entails restarting all its subordinates, similarly terminating an actor will also terminate all its subordinates

What I suspect is that it is our responsibility to create child(ren) in the `preStart` method because Akka's term *RESTART* is no reSTART unless you create the children recursively and explicitly in their parent `preStart()` method.

Example (using Akka 2.0 & 2.2-SNAPSHOT): no matter what I try, children are always just stopped, never restarted in this test case. I create `Supervisor` -> `First` -> `Second` relationship and throw exception in the `Supervisor`. What happens is that `supervisor` is restarted and `First` & `Second` stopped.

```
  test("restart test") {
    val system = ActorSystem("test")
    val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props(new Supervisor), "supervisor")
    supervisor ! CREATE(Props(new First), "first")
    Thread.sleep(500)

    val first = system.actorFor("akka://test/user/supervisor/first")
    first ! CREATE(Props(new Second), "second")
    Thread.sleep(500)
    supervisor ! WTF

    Thread.sleep(20000)
  }

  case object WTF
  case class CREATE(p: Props, name: String)

  class Supervisor extends Actor {
    override val supervisorStrategy =
      OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10) {
        case _: IllegalStateException       => Restart
        case _: IllegalArgumentException    => Stop
        case _: Exception                   => Restart
    }
    override def preStart() {
      println(s"$self starts")
    }
    override def postStop() {
      println(s"$self stopped")
    }
    override def receive = {
      case WTF => println("throwing exception"); throw new IllegalStateException()
      case CREATE(p, name) => context.actorOf(p, name)
    }
  }
  class First extends Actor {
    override def preStart() {
      println(s"$self starts")
    }
    override def postStop() {
      println(s"$self stopped")
    }
    override def receive = {
      case WTF => println("throwing exception"); throw new IllegalStateException()
      case CREATE(p, name) => context.actorOf(p, name)
    }
  }
  class Second extends Actor {
    override def preStart() {
      println(s"$self starts")
    }
    override def postStop() {
      println(s"$self stopped")
    }
    override def receive = {
      case WTF => println("throwing exception"); throw new IllegalStateException()
      case CREATE => sender ! "ok"
    }
  }
```

> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor#1599926629] starts
> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor/first#2012011668] starts
> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor/first/second#1750038710] starts
>
> throwing exception Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor#1599926629]
> stopped [ERROR] [06/26/2013 11:11:16.899]
> [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://test/user/supervisor]
> null java.lang.IllegalStateException at
> com.fg.mail.smtp.IntegrationSuite$Supervisor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(IntegrationSuite.scala:40)
> at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498) at
> akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456) at
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237) at
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219) at
> akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
> at
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
> at
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
> at
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
> at
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
>
> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor/first/second#1750038710] stopped
> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor/first#2012011668] stopped
> Actor[akka://test/user/supervisor#1599926629] starts

Answer (score 6):

Your suspicion is correct. If you look carefully at the 7-step description of the restart process on http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html, you will see:

> 2 . ... defaults to sending termination requests to all children ...

and

> 6 . send restart request to all children **which were not killed**

So, you need to either override the parent's `preRestart` hook to stop Akka killing the children, or override `postRestart` to re-create all the children that were just killed.

Which you choose really depends on the semantics of your application. Sometimes it's useful to kill the entire hierarchy and start with a blank slate, sometimes not.

Comment: Well it's a shame there's no third option that would just restart the children implicitly... If you think about it the only safe way of forming hierarchy is creating descendant actors in their parent's preStart() method. Any other way would be quite complicated to achieve.

Comment: The documentation is quite ambiguous because they're writing about "restarting" everywhere and it actually means "calling" preRestart and postRestart lifecycle methods, but it is your responsibility to care about the actual re"STARTING"

Comment: No? If you create your children in the constructor or preStart then the children are automatically re-created when the parent is restarted.

Comment: Viktor: yes, they are ... but akka documentation's term restart ain't no RESTART, unless you do what you say - and this is totally missing in the entire documentation

Comment: Btw do you know how to piecefully restart Actor except for throwing an exception ? I can't find a way of invoking the effect of throwing an exception within the process of handling a message. Consider you are in the top actor, calling context.stop(self) which stops all its children, but how to restart myself ?