# Akka error in scala 2.13 upgrade fails when trying to bind actors in configure method: cannot create children while terminating or terminated

Tags: scala, akka

I have a play app in scala 2.13 which used to work well in 2.12. Here's my module which extends `AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport`:

```
class TimerModule(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
   // rest of the code
   def configure(): Unit = {
    val actorSystemProvider = this.getProvider(classOf[ActorSystem])
    bindActor[TimerActor]("actor-1")
    bindActor[InvocationLogActor]("actor-2")
    bind(classOf[ExecutionContext])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("blocking-tasks"))
      .toProvider(classOf[BlockingTaskDispatcherProvider])

    bindActor[ClusterEventListener]("actor-3")
    bindActor[ClusterSingletonProxy]("actor-4", _ => Actor4.props(
      singletonManagerPath = "/user/caller-actor",
      settings = Actor4Settings(actorSystemProvider.get())))
   }

}
```

The code compiles well however upon runtime, I am getting an error that says:

```
Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot create children while terminating or terminated at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport.bindActor(AkkaGuiceSupport.scala:76)
```

I read about other threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130391/why-does-akka-fail-with-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-children-while-ter) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314319/whose-responsibility-is-creating-akka-actors-children-when-it-fails) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431784/exception-on-stop-when-using-actorsystem-and-guice) but still not getting why its failing for me. Any leads is highly apprecicated